# c# Date component bug or am i missing something?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a huge problem with the following code:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
String yearmonthday = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
MessageBox.Show(yearmonthday);
```

the problem is, C# uses the system date separator instead of always using "/" as i specified. If I run that code, I get the following output:

```
2011/03/18
```

but if I go to "control panel" -> "regional and language options" and change the date separator to "-", I get

```
2011-03-18
```

Even if in the toString method I specified to use '/' . Am I missing something or this is a C#  / .Net Framework bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/` in your format string is [a placeholder for the date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) -- the behaviour that you're seeing is by design and clearly documented.

If you need a literal `/` then [you need to escape it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#escape) in your format string, which should then look something like *"yyyy\/MM\/dd"* or *"yyyy'/'MM'/'dd"*.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

```
String yearmonthday = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or escape the `/`

```
String yearmonthday = date.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");
```

Comment: Ok, now it works. Btw, seems rather stupid to have to specify that paramether if I write the exact format i want in the string...

Comment: @kaharas, `/` has a special meaning in the format => it represents the date separator for the current culture.

Comment: @kaharas, Aliostad: Why does it seem stupid? Would you expect `dd` or `yyyy` to appear verbatim in the formatted string too?

Comment: @LukeH : the first 2 answers, didn't say anything about the "/ is the placeholder for date separator", but just tolf me to add the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture parameter. And, if that was the case ( C# reset the format to use the system date separator), don't you agree it would have been quite stupid? I see now, the "escape /" has been added :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that / is reserved for the date character - so this isn't a bug - it's a feature that this gets interpreted according to the locale.

Try escpaing the / character with:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
d.ToString("yy\\/mm\\/dd").Dump();
```

Answer (score 2):

`InvariantCulture` should do the trick

```
String yearmonthday = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get '-' or ":" based on the formats that you supply . refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the / is a date separator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

if you need custom separator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator

so the behavior is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `/` character, since it is the date separator, like this:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
var s = d.ToString(@"yyyy\/MM\/dd");
```

Read all about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently by design.

The work is implemented in an internal class called `DateTimeFormat` which you can see this snippet in `FormatCustomized` method:

```
 case '/':
        {
            outputBuffer.Append(dtfi.DateSeparator);
            num2 = 1;
            continue;
        }
```

So it replaces `/` with `DateSeparator`.